# × ReferenceError: Home is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I wanted to import react router to my components and got the error as described in the 'title'!

btw I'm doing it from a tutorial crash course!

I will show my files below

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import About from "./Pages/About";
import Profile from "./Pages/Profile";


function App() {
return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Header />
  </div>
  <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} /> 
  <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
</BrowserRouter>
);
}
export default App;
```

Home.js

```
const Home = () => {
return <h1>Home Page</h1>;
};

export default Home;
```

About.js

```
const About = () => {
return <h1>About Page</h1>;
};

export default About;
```

Profile.js

```
const Profile = () => {
return <h1>Profile Page</h1>;
};

export default Profile;
```

Header.js

```
const Header = () => {
return (
    <>
        <h1>React Router Dom</h1>
    </>
)
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Are you importing your component correctly? Are other pages working fine or it's just 'Home' ??

Comment: it's working , just some technical issues! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is in `"./Pages/Home"` ? Can you try putting `Home` component code above

```
function App()
```

to see if it will show the same error

Comment: it's working , just some technical issues! thanks!